# Derive Timezone name, offset from abbrevation

Tags: java, grails

Do we need store timezone_offset, timezone_name, timezone_abbr or just one and derive the rest? If we can derive from one than How can I do that. It can be in `Grails` or `Java`

Comment: You can't derive the name from the abbreviation, basically. There can be multiple time zones which are all currently observing the same offset with the same abbreviation, but which will deviate from each other at a different time. The name is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the IANA timezone name, e.g. `Europe/London`.

- The timezone offset is only relevant on a particular day (e.g. it is wrong when daylight savings changes)
- The [timezone abbreviation is ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) (e.g. CST is "Central Standard Time" (which *itself* is ambiguous, as both Australia and the US use to refer to different timezones), "Central Summer Time" and "China Standard Time").